# How to compose monad transformers in scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

How to make this compile, or do something similar?

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val ee: Future[Unit \/ Option[Int]] = Future(\/-(Option(1)))
OptionT.optionT(EitherT.eitherT(ee))
```

Comment: What are you trying to model here? How does a failed future differ from a future that succeeds with `()` on the left side or a `None` on the right?

Comment: It is a simplified example. You could substitute any type you like instead of Unit and Int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the types explicitly (also `OptionT.optionT` appears to do something slightly different):

```
//could use a type lambda, but this is (IMO) slightly clearer
type FutureEither[A] = EitherT[Future, Unit, A]
new OptionT[FutureEither, Int](EitherT.eitherT[Future, Unit, Option[Int]](ee))
```

(I should probably mention my [scalaz-transfigure](https://github.com/m50d/scalaz-transfigure) library as a slightly lighter and more inferencey approach to doing the same thing that monad transformers do; it's not terribly mature yet though)

Comment: I think `OptionT#optionT` is simply `OptionT#apply` implemented as a natural transformation so as to avoid the need to repeat the contained type: `optionT[FutureEither](EitherT(ee))`.